# "Offensive defense spending" versus "defensive defense spending"

Tags: armed-conflict, international-relations, military

It seems to me that some defense spending has the objective of reducing or eliminating civilian and/or military casualties resulting from attacks on home soil. For instance: investment in domestic anti-air facilities, submarines equipped to deal with nearby ships and/or other submarines (but unable to hit land targets, say). I also have the [MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_Defense_Agency) and similar programs in mind. Lets call this "defensive" defense spending. It seems to me that most military spending in the present-day is not of this kind; i.e. most military spending is "offensive" defense spending, designed to take the battle elsewhere. The best defense is a good offense; or at least, that seems to be the thinking behind this kind of expenditure.

Notwithstanding the short-term risks associated with defensive defense spending, such as destabilizing international relationships predicated on mutually-assured destruction, it seems reasonable to believe that in the long-term, its basically a good thing. More specifically, I expect that the greater the ratio of each military budget that is used in defensive defense projects, the better the prospects are for the world's civilian population. It may even be possible to run simulations that predict a tipping-point for this ratio; on one side of this ratio, we have the extinction of much or all of human life, while on the other side, humanity continues to exist, at least for awhile (until the relevant incentive structures change, say).

Anyway, I know nothing about any of this, but I'm sure the above framework has been thought about, studied, and criticized already. My question is:

> **Question.** Regarding military spending, what are the main positions on the idea of an offensive/defensive distinction, is this distinction widely thought to be a reasonable and meaningful distinction or not, and where can I learn more about the main positions in this debate?

I'd be especially interested in mathematical (e.g. game-theoretic perspectives.)

Comment: Defensive only spending would be mostly useless. If you cannot go out and stop the enemy from attacking you again and again, you will lose eventually. You can make it costly to attack, but that's all.

Comment: @Cyrus, Re "*mostly useless*":  If defensive defense is cheaper, then a defender vs offender match where both sides have equal resources to start, the defender has the advantage, and can stalemate the offender until the offender goes broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure why this question attracted so many downvotes.  While there are often overlaps between offensive and defensive weapons, claiming there is no difference is a bit of a stretch.

#### offensive (tanks) vs defensive (anti tank missiles)

Tanks - a tank is meant to cover ground quickly and penetrate deep behind enemy lines.  It's not really designed, or cost-effective, for defense.

Anti-tank missiles.  Can be a cost effective solution to limiting the scope for enemy armor attacks.  Even if top-end modern tanks can shrug off most ATM, their accompanying infantry vehicles can't.  Left to their own, tanks will not do well against infantry, especially in cities.

#### SAMs vs aircraft

The same logic can, again, be applied to aircraft and Surface to Air Missiles.

In high-intensity warfare missiles are typically much cheaper than what they destroy, so defense-based deterrence can be cheaper than a more balanced offense-defense force.

#### attack helicopters

If you have the $$$, attack helicopters can present a serious risk to enemy armor while being of negligible offensive value on their own.  Leading up to Gulf War I, if I recall correctly, some were postulating a 17-1 likely kill ratio, to the advantage of helicopters.  The lack of actual peer-to-peer high-intensity warfare has left that unproven.

#### building your military posture around defense

For example, from [Deterring Russian Aggression](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_reports/RR2700/RR2779/RAND_RR2779.pdf):

> TD/UW involves mostly
> defensive capabilities
> and is thus less likely
> to be characterized
> as provocative or
> escalatory than
> increases in national
> or NATO conventional
> military forces

#### Infantry

Likewise, Switzerland has long concentrated on making itself a hard country to invade, rather than a country with a high capacity for invading others.  This is partially done by having a lot of reservist infantry (and a very helpful geography).

#### short range units

Some Taiwanese experts are arguing for deploying smaller coastal submarines as a deterrent to Chinese threats of invasion.  Nordic countries have long deployed rather small coastal combat ships that are meant to operate within their coastline but still carry potent [anti ship missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Strike_Missile).  These are not units that present a large offensive capability of carrying combat to the enemy.

#### Fortifications:

If your terrain supports it, extra care can be taken to fortify bottlenecks.

#### some examples:

In the 2006 invasion of Lebanon, Israel lost quite a lot tanks to [Hezbollah anti-tank missiles](https://www.haaretz.com/1.4860368).  I doubt that Israel will be casual in contemplating a ground advance into Lebanon in the future (FWIW, I do not begrudge Israel taking steps to neutralize enemy fire coming out of a sovereign neighboring country like Lebanon).

Afghanistan 1980-1989.  With the introduction of Stingers, Soviet military posture, already under strain, became very compromised when they lost the ability to deploy attack and troop transport helicopters without risk.

China's initial navy build up seems to be about limiting the capacity of the US Navy to conduct operations near China.  China's intentions may, or may not, be benign, but few can argue that the Chinese navy represents a threat to the US on the high seas.

So it is possible to enhance a country's capacity to deny its territory to other countries while taking care not to project an image of aggressive potential.  The risk is that defensive weapon systems are typically not very mobile and an enemy may still prevail by massing at particular locations or by employing counter-methods like artillery.  Finally, the enemy can just re-group, re-structure and re-attack.

Defense-only will not win a war, true.  But it can make calculations of a cheap war dissuasively risky to the attacker if they do not have really good reasons to attack you.

This is, again, pretty much what the Baltic and Nordic countries defensive strategy is wrt Russia, so claiming it just isn't done is just not backed up by facts.

Comment: "The risk is that defensive weapon systems are typically not very mobile and an enemy may still prevail" - happened in World War II with the Maginot-Line...
Regarding the Nordic states - I do believe they have attack aircraft, tanks as well, not only fortifications.

Answer (score 6):

Military spending can not be easily separated into offensive spending and defensive spending, because many military assets are dual-use. They can be used both to defend the own territory and to attack other states.

A batallion of infantry can occupy an enemy town or defend an own against an invader. A tank can fight enemy tanks on own or on foreign soil. An artillery battery can slow the enemies advance or shell a city. A figher jet can intercept enemy bombers or drop bombs on enemy positions.

There are some assets which are definitely offensive in nature when you look at them from a purely military perspective, like intercontinental missiles, long-range bombers or aircraft carriers. But from a political perspective they aren't. Such weapon systems often serve as a deterrent to prevent other states from pursuing military actions out of fear of retaliation. States have these weapon systems so they *don't* have to use them.

Also, actions which seem like offensive military actions are sometimes justified as preventive measures to ensure future stability. Former German minister of defense Peter Struck once justified the German contribution to the war in Afghanistan with *"The German safety is also defended at the Hindu Kush"* (The German constitution explicitly forbids to use the Bundeswehr offensively, so he had no choice but to argument along such lines).

But there are also defensive measures which support offensive military actions by making a counter-attack less feasible. A historic example is the fortification of European coasts by the Nazis during World War II. A more modern example is the US Department of Homeland Security which has the primary purpose to prevent retaliation for US military actions.

As you can see, a strict separation between offensive military spending and defensive military spending doesn't make much sense in politics, because most military spending can serve both purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between offensive and defensive technology has, if anything, grown harder to make over time, rather than easier.

As a general rule, passive armor and defensive measures in modern warfare can almost always be defeated by a much lighter, less expensive offensive weapon.

An infantryman can effectively deploy an anti-tank or anti-aircraft missile. A small fighter aircraft can carry a missile or torpedo capable of sinking most warships. The modern trend is towards active defenses such as a Patriot missile that involves, essentially, shooting down a bullet with another bullet. At the moment, politics have caused tactical nuclear weapons to be disavowed, but it is technologically possible for a man with a heavy backpack to carry a nuclear weapon capable of leveling an entire town, village or military formation.

The days of castles and fortified strongholds and trenches as something important in military strategy is long gone as bunker buster bombs carried by aircraft or designed as cruise missiles can destroy almost any fortification.

Also, as a result of longstanding military dominance, the forces whose primary mission is to defend the continental United States at home (in the case of the United States military), i.e. the National Guard and the Coast Guard, make up only a tiny and underpowered share of the total military force, because there are no "near peer" militaries likely to launch such an invasion, movies like *Red Dawn* notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1):

In the modern world there is no meaningful distinction between offensive and defensive weapons on a strategic scale.

An extreme example is strategic nuclear weapons, particularly ICBMs, their actual function is purely offensive but politically and strategically their stated purpose is defence in the sense that they deter any attack, at least by a state.

Equally something like anti-aircraft batteries which are in function purely defensive may still be vital assets in prosecuting an offensive war. The same also goes for non-combat assets like logistics which are just as important and often more expensive and difficult in an offensive rather than defensive role. A big chunk of the expense of operations in Afghanistan and Iraq is the cost of getting military hardware and consumables into theatre, especially as most of the routes in by air and (especially) land are far form secure. While most states maintain some sort of high mobility force at say brigade level which can transport it's own organic combined arms assets around the world these are really intended for rapid intervention and still require massive support operations to sustain their effectiveness and often lack the specialist units for a long campaign.

Equally on a tactical level no military commander would want to run a purely defensive campaign.  at some point you need to be able to counterattack or you are just stuck defending a fixed position as you then sacrifice all ability to manoeuvre and surrender the initiative to the enemy, even a defensive strategy tends to rely on some ability to counter attack to achieve defence in depth. For example in WW1 many of the initial attacks were quite successful in taking ground (even the Battle of the Somme) but ended up achieving little because the attacking forces became over-extended beyond the ability of their logistics and command and control to cope and found themselves in untenable positions and vulnerable to counter-attack.

In general most democratic nations call all military spending 'defence' because it sounds better. For example in the UK the *War Office* was replaced by the *Ministry of Defence*.